# Copy-Item Recursive by *FILE* date modified, but keep folder

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm a bit stumped by this one, so I'm working to automate a particular process for WSUS in an offline environment. Basically just prepping the export of files after they've been approved manually and getting them ready to burn to CD for the isolated environment.

It needs to do a few things. First, it needs to clean the export folder (check), make a complete replica of the existing WSUS folder in a new location (check), identify how many new files were uploaded into that replica location (check), copy ONLY those new files to an export folder maintaining the folder structure, EVEN if the folder is empty (check...kinda). My problem is that when the files move over, they are outside of the folders... And of course, logging...

I'm testing this on my personal laptop with a mock environment. So, here's my code so far...

```
##Set directory locations and variables
$nicedate = Get-Date -UFormat %m-%d-%Y
$source = "C:\temp\WsusContent\"
$bckp = "C:\temp2\WsusContent"
$dest = "C:\temp2\export"
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-28)
$log = "C:\temp\wsus_log_$nicedate.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source

##Delete all subfolders and Files from destination
Get-ChildItem $dest | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

#Duplicate new Files (i.e. delta.bat)
try{
    xcopy /E/H/D/C/I/Y $source $bckp
    Write-Output("BACKUP:     WSUS Backup complete")
}
catch{"ERROR:     Backup Failed"}

##Log events
Start-Transcript -Path $log

##Copy source Files and folder structure to destination
foreach($file in $files){
    $fname = $file.fullname
    $fdate = $file.LastWriteTime
    if($fdate -gt $date){
       (Copy-Item $fname -Destination $dest -PassThru).count
    }
}
 
#End logging
Get-Date
Stop-Transcript
```

This is how they end up:
[Export Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyoVZ.png)

What am I missing to get these files to move within the folders, but still using the FILE modified date (because I don't want to get all the old wsus updates)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more suitable answer for my needs. This one uses the generated log file to specify what files to copy since the new WSUS files from Microsoft don't always have a "Last Modified" date within the 30 day marker:

```
##Set directory locations and variables
$org = "C:\Temp\WsusContent"
$bckp = "C:\temp2\WsusContent"
$source = "C:\Temp\WsusContent\"
$dest = "C:\temp2\export\"
$log = "C:\temp\wsus_log.txt"
$dlog = "C:\temp\deltalog.txt"
$elog = "C:\temp\temp_log.txt"

##Delete all subfolders and Files from destination
Write-Output("Deleting export folder...")
Get-ChildItem $dest | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
Write-Output("Deletion complete. Export folder empty.")

#Duplicate new Files (i.e. delta.bat)
Write-Output("Backing up WSUS folder.")
Write-Output("Logging started...")
try{
    xcopy $org $bckp /i /d /e /y > $dlog
    Write-Output("WSUS Backup complete. Log output file is $dlog")
}
catch{"ERROR:     Backup Failed"}

##Create usable file. Remove the 'X File(s) copied' line.
$path = Get-Content -Path $dlog | Select-String -Pattern "C:\" -SimpleMatch
Set-Content -Path $elog -Value $path

##Log events
Start-Transcript -Path $log

##Copy folder structure to destination
$folders = Get-ChildItem $source -Directory
foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $fname = $folder.FullName
    Copy-Item $fname -Destination $dest
}

##Copy new files to export using temp_log.txt
$files = Get-Content -Path $elog
$count = foreach ($string in $files){
    $sourcefolder = $string.Replace($source,"")
    $newdest = $dest + $sourcefolder
    Write-Output $newdest
    Copy-Item $files $newdest
}

##Count files moved to export
$total = $count.Count
Write-Output $count 
Write-Output("$total Files copied")

#End logging
Get-Date
Stop-Transcript

# $nicedate = Get-Date -UFormat %m-%d-%Y

##Start WSUS Utility
# Write-Output("Starting wsusutil...")
# Set-Location "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools"
# Start-Process wsusutil.exe export E:\$nicedate-export.xml.gz E:\$nicedate-export.log
# Write-Output("wsusutil completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was able to get it working with the following script:

```
##Set directory locations and variables
$nicedate = Get-Date -UFormat %m-%d-%Y
$source = "C:\temp\WsusContent\"
$bckp = "C:\temp2\WsusContent\"
$dest = "C:\temp2\export\"
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-28)
$log = "C:\temp\wsus_log_$nicedate.txt"

##Delete all subfolders and Files from destination
Get-ChildItem $dest | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

##Duplicate new files (i.e. delta.bat)
try{
    xcopy /E/H/D/C/I/Y $source $bckp > "C:\temp\delta_$nicedate.log"
    Write-Output("BACKUP:     WSUS Backup complete")
}
catch{"ERROR:     Backup Failed"}

##Log events
Start-Transcript -Path $log 

##Copy source files and folder structure to destination
$folders = Get-ChildItem $source -Directory
$count = foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $fname = $folder.FullName
    Copy-Item $fname -Destination $dest
    $files = Get-ChildItem $fname -File
    foreach ($file in $files){
        $fname = $file.FullName
        $sourcefolder = $fname.Replace($source,"")
        $newdest = $dest + $sourcefolder
        if($file.LastWriteTime -gt $date){
            Write-Output $newdest
            Copy-Item $fname -Destination $newdest
        }
    }
}
$total = $count.Count
Write-Output $count 
Write-Output("$total Files moved")
 
##End logging
Get-Date
Stop-Transcript

##Run the WSUS Utility export
Set-Location "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools" 
Start-Process wsusutil.exe export "E:\$nicedate-export.xml.gz" "E:\$nicedate-export.log"
```